# Create Joomla module to display custom tooltip on hover

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I need to develop a custom module that displays a tooltip on hovering module contents. I wanted to use the joomla default for this, but I had an inconvenience.

I need to display a small arrow pointing to the current hovered module item, and, in the case that the tooltip may display on the other side of the module item (because is too close to the page edge), it must change the arrow to point it to the other side of the tooltip. Please see image for more details.

Tooltip appearing on hovering menu item
[image: tooltip on hovering module item]

Tooltip appearing on hovering menu item, but changing arrow because is too close to the page right edge
[image]

Is that possible, or I need another tooltip solution for this?

Comment: Just added two screenshots of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For custom tool tips, have a look at some of the extensions on the [Tooltip](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/article-elements/tooltips) category on the Joomla Extensions Directory site.

The top 3 have good ratings and are Joomla 2.5 compatible so try one of those.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but none of them sorts the issue of showing the tooltip when is too close to the page edge, like joomla std tooltip behaiviour does. That would be just ok, but my client wants to show that arrow pointing to the hovered menu item, no mather the direction of the tooltip.

Comment: @razor7: have your tried anything of your own yet? Might be an idea to use one of the extensions list in the link I provided, change the styling to suit your needs, then search on Google for preventing the tooltip from overlapping the page if it's too close. I'm sure it will be a simple bit of javascript

Comment: Thats the trick, I'm looking for help on this because I don't even know where to start looking. Will investigate thoose plugins furter. Thanks!